# kill the "electical" tag because it is a mis-spelling

Tags: support, status-completed

The tag "electical" just a mis-spelling of electrical, and should be deleted.

https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/electical/info

Comment: Ooh... my first tag wiki edit got approved!

Answer (score 3):

I retagged the question with [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical).

I don't think we need do any more than that. The system automatically removes unused tags after 24 hours, so by this time tomorrow it will no longer be suggested when you start typing in the tags field.

For now, when you type "elect" in the tags field, the [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) tag is the first one suggested at the top left. "electical" is at the bottom right and is much less noticeable, IMO, so I doubt it'll be reused.

Comment: You could always merge the misspelling into the proper tag to stop it reappearing.